# Drop Down Pageblock

Tags: visualforce

[image: Drop Down]Above i created the 2 page-blocks for less records it showing fine, if i have more records means i want to drop down feature for 2 page blocks how can i get it Any Suggestions My Code Is

```
   <apex:pageblock title="Accounts">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="ar">
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
            {!ar['n']}
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Duplicate Count">
            {!ar['c']}
        </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageblock>
<apex:pageblock title="Contacts">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="ar">
        <apex:column headerValue="Contact Name">
            {!ar['n']}
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Duplicate Count">
            {!ar['c']}
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageblock>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to wrap your `apex:pageBlockTable` in an `apex:pageBlockSection` because that component provides the collapsing feature. Experiment with putting the title on the `apex:pageBlockSection` instead of or as well as on the `apex:pageblock`.